# Is there any way to return only limited length from multi array in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any way to return only limited length from multi-array in PHP? I'm trying to use array_slice and seems not working for me.

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5216
            [name] => Grow your own Irish Shamrock gifts set
            [ordered] => 473
            [image] => FunShamrockPot.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5217
            [name] => Irish Shamrock Seeds
            [ordered] => 357
            [image] => FunShamrockSeed.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5759
            [name] => Ireland Fleece with Shamrock Badge
            [ordered] => 1
            [image] => IrelandFleeceShamrocks.jpg
        )
```

I tried this and it's not working:

```
$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/core_db/database.json'), true);
usort($jsonData, "sortFunction");

$jsonFiltered = array();

if (empty($question)) {
    if (is_int(intval($maxCount)) && intval($maxCount) != 0) {
        $count = intval($maxCount);

        array_slice($jsonData, 0, $count);
    } else {
        array_slice($jsonData, 0, 20);
    }
}
```

It's an example from Stackoverflow. And I wanted to return only 0-1 arrays. Is there any way to do this with PHP function only, not foreach thing? If yes, please let me know. If no, can you please tell me.

I was using this method for this:

```
        $count = intval($maxCount);
        $maxDBCount = count($jsonData);

        if ($count > $maxDBCount) {
            $count = $maxDBCount;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
            $jsonFiltered[] = $jsonData[$i];

            if ($i >= $count) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, if you use `array_slice($jsonData, 0, 20);` you will get the 20 first elements. If you want the 2 firsts, use `array_slice($jsonData, 0, 2);`

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm asking here. I tried that and it returns only blank array []. I can't find why so I posted here :(

Comment: Show us the piece of code with `array_slice()`

Comment: By the way, you don't need `if ($i >= $count) { break; }`

Comment: I edited my question with my piece of code. Please check. However, array_slice doesn't work for me in unknown reasons and I want to know if I'm wrong or there is 
 any better solutions.

Comment: Of course you get something empty, you never catch the return value of `array_slice`

Comment: $question is a search parameter, if no search string is queried, it will just return first 20 values.

Comment: `$jsonFiltered = array_slice();` it does't slice the array in place, but returns a copy sliced

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm really stupid. I modified my code to $jsonFiltered = array_slice($jsonData, 0, $count); and it works. Thank you for catching my mistake, Cid!